# What does this "update database with panache Entity" in Java?

Tags: java

I try to update my database.
When it updates there is a single line that duplicates everywhere.

```java
Person person = update(person2.getId(),person2);

if (person.getLocalDate()!= tableFile.getLocalDate()) {

  entry.forEach(entr -> {
    person.setAaid(entr.getAaid());
    person.setLocalDate(entr.getLocalDate());
    person.persist();
  }

}
```

Can you help me to understand this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use proper code-formatting and ask a clear question (I prepared this for you). Ask specifically for __what__ you don't understood. See also the guide [ask]. [Edit] your question and specify: (1) where the line is you don't understood (may comment in code) and (2) what you do not understand.